# Edit champ xaml with concatenation string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, loops, concatenation

I have in my xaml files 6 value similar a that:

```
<TextBlock Name="Player0" Visibility="Hidden" Text="Player 0" />
<TextBlock Name="Player1" Visibility="Hidden" Text="Player 1" />
...
```

but i want to change Visibilty with a for loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
  String test = "Player" + i;
  test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Usually one would [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) an `ItemsControl` to a list of objects, bind the visibility of the items to a property on those objects and then just change that property. See also [data templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  TextBlock test = (TextBlock)this.FindName("Player" + i);
  test.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what i need. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your objects' type in xaml file is TextBlock, but its in cs file is String.
Are you sure?
 If you are, Change class type in cs file like,

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
     var block = this.FindName("Player"+i) as TextBlock;
     if (block!=null)
     {
         block.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     }
}
```